# Rails Simple-form Hijri(Ismalic Calendar) Calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, simple-form

I am using rails 3 for a Human Resource App, For providing access to the Middle east clients i customized my app with Hijri (Islamic) Calendar.

But in the edit option of the employee, I use the default simple_form function to generate the dropdown

with this code
`<%=   f.input :iqidate,end_year: Date.today.year,start_year:1960  %>`

But by default this is generated in Gregorian calendar. And i want to know  what should i tweak this function to generate the islamic calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date fields you are dealing with are just Ruby date libaries, so I would recommend a using a Ruby library for converting the date to hijri within ruby.  This stackoverflow post may be of help for picking the right one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569827/is-there-any-hijri-date-library-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks Kelseydh, I tried it but no luck. I installed the https://github.com/stormvirux/hijri2greg_date gem and tried this code             <%=   f.input :iqidate,end_year: Date.today.to_hijri.year,start_year:1960  %> , but it's giving error , could you help me where i should do this convertion. I need islamic calendar html dropdown to be generated in the form